# Href asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, html, css, вёрстка, asp.net

Пытаюсь сделать ссылку по якорям.

Работает только от футера (от низа и вверх). А вот от хедера и к любому элементу ниже него не работает, из-за чего такое может быть

Якоря делаю правильно, пример снизу

```
<div name="myattr" class="navbar-header">
</div>

<a href="#myattr"><img width="100" height="100" src="~/Content/Images/logo_footer.png"/></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tам `id` надо указывать:

```
<div id="myattr" ...
```

Атрибут `name` работает для линков:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html

```css
.spacer{
background:green;
margin:10px;
height:100px;
}

.navbar-header{
background:red;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<a name="myattr" class="navbar-header">AAA
</a>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<a href="#myattr"><img width="100" height="100" src="~/Content/Images/logo_footer.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Странно,  навверх и без id работало. Делал по примеру http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya

Comment: @SOFL См. ссылку в ответе.